# Null value getting returned after ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Kindly go through the below text below marking this as duplicate.

I am having function parameters in the ajax function and hence unable to understand how to use a callback. Please suggest a working code for the below mentioned scenario.

I am trying to retrieve a value from a JSON object obtained after parsing it from a text file received from an ajax call.

```
var stockInfo = passCodes(z,i,j);
```

Here passCodes is a function with an ajax call being made to a URL that transmits a text response.

```
function passCodes(arg1,arg2,arg3){// these arguments are used to build URL
alert("inside passcodes");
var json={};
$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: "url.com",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(resp) {
        resp = resp.match(/{.+}/)[0]; //to remove the garbage text
        json=JSON.parse(resp); // json object created perfectly
        return json.key1.key2;

    },
    error: function(resp) {
        alert("An error occurred while processing response");
    }


});
```

Comment: If I had a nickel for each asynchronous dupe...

Comment: Please check the duplicate marked question, asynchorous callbacks are tricky to understand. Give it some time, read the answers there with a little patience, you can find working code there too.